# IMB PCF agent returns error while inquiring channel status

Tags: java, ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus

I have a problem with PCF message agent while inquiring channel in order to obtain informations about hosts connected to a given queue manager. The code of PCFAgent is

```
 MQGetMessageOptions getMessageOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions();
 getMessageOptions.options = MQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_NEXT + MQC.MQGMO_NO_WAIT + MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
 messageAgent = new PCFMessageAgent(MQEnvironment.hostname, MQEnvironment.port, MQEnvironment.channel);
```

and code of options is

```
 inquireOptions = new PCFMessage(CMQCFC.MQCMD_INQUIRE_CHANNEL_STATUS);
            inquireOptions.addParameter(CMQCFC.MQCACH_CHANNEL_NAME, "*");
            inquireOptions.addParameter(CMQCFC.MQIACH_CHANNEL_INSTANCE_TYPE, CMQC.MQOT_CURRENT_CHANNEL);
            inquireOptions.addParameter(CMQCFC.MQIACH_CHANNEL_INSTANCE_ATTRS, new int[]{
                    CMQCFC.MQCACH_CHANNEL_NAME, CMQCFC.MQCACH_CONNECTION_NAME, CMQCFC.MQIACH_MSGS,
                    CMQCFC.MQCACH_LAST_MSG_DATE, CMQCFC.MQCACH_LAST_MSG_TIME, CMQCFC.MQIACH_CHANNEL_STATUS
            });
            responses = messageAgent.send(inquireOptions);
```

Not always, but occasionally the application resturns an exception that says "Completion Code 2, Reason 2100" and my host (the one on which the application is running) leaves a pending connection on the server that is never closed until the MQManager is restarted.

I've read that this exception is due to a conflict in creating dynamic queues, but in my code I don't create any queue.
Someone could help me? Sorry, I've no previous experiences with queue managers.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

[2100 (MQRC_OBJECT_ALREADY EXISTS)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q041610_.htm) is indeed a problem with creating a dynamic queue.

> **Explanation**
>
> An MQOPEN call was issued to create a dynamic queue, but a queue with the same name as the dynamic queue already exists.
>
> **Completion code**
>
> MQCC_FAILED
>
> **Programmer response**
>
> If supplying a dynamic queue name in full, ensure that it obeys the naming conventions for dynamic queues; if it does, either supply a different name, or delete the existing queue if it is no longer required. Alternatively, allow the queue manager to generate the name.
>
> If the queue manager is generating the name (either in part or in full), reissue the MQOPEN call.

Under the covers, the `PCFMessageAgent` will create a PCF Format message using the details you supply in the `PCFMessage` and will open a model queue to create a temporary queue in order to receive the reply from the Command Server. These temporary queues are named by the queue manager by producing a unique portion using a timestamp, resulting in a name something like `AMQ.5E47207E2227AA02`. If you have lots of concurrent applications doing this, it is possible that you could end up with a clash of names, and the second request in, at the same time might get a name conflict.

If you have a way to make the temporary queue name more unique should such concurrency be a problem in your system, you can set the prefix used for the temporary queue name using the [setReplyQueuePrefix](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJavaClasses/com/ibm/mq/headers/pcf/PCFAgent.html#setReplyQueuePrefix-java.lang.String-) method. You could, for example, user the user ID each application is running under, if that is unique.

> **public void setReplyQueuePrefix(java.lang.String prefixP)**
>
> Sets the string used as the first part of the agent's reply queue name. The reply queue used by the PCFAgent is a temporary dynamic queue. By default, the reply queue prefix used by the PCFAgent is the empty string (""). When this is used, the name of the reply queue is generated entirely by the queue manager. If the method is called with a prefix specified, then the PCFAgent will pass that prefix to the queue manager whenever it needs to create a temporary queue. The queue manager will then generate the rest of the temporary queue name. This means that the queue manager generates a unique name, but the PCFAgent still has some control. The prefix specified should be fewer than 33 characters. If the prefix contains 33 characters or greater, then this method will truncate the prefix to be 32 characters in length. If the prefix does not contain an asterisk (*) character at the end, then an asterisk will be added to the end.

Comment: This post was really useful for me for understanding some of the nature of the PCFMessageAgent. I was wondering if you could point to any IBM documentation that details the internal behavior of the Agent in regard to temporary queues?

Comment: Hi @AHungerArtist - the link in the answer above details all the PCFAgent methods, including setReplyQueuePrefix. It briefly says, "By default, the reply queue prefix used by the PCFAgent is the empty string (""). When this is used, the name of the reply queue is generated entirely by the queue manager." Is that what you are looking for? Or something else?